# Почему "в упор" пишется раздельно?

Tags: наречия

Почему, когда вдаль, вверх, вглубь, ввысь, вконец, вмиг и др. пишутся слитно, то в упор - раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Есть простое правило: наречия пишутся раздельно, если после "в" едет гласная буква (в упор, в открытую, в отместку)

Comment: да?

Вообще? вокруг?

Answer (score 1):

Виктор1799 прав по сути - за исключением формулировки. Речь идет только о наречиях, во форме представляющих собой сочетания предлога **в** и существительного в форме винительного падежа - т.е. эквивалентные предложным формам существительных, отвечающим на вопрос "во что?" ("в кого?", "куда?").

> 1. Пишутся раздельно наречные сочетания, состоящие из предлога в и существительных, начинающихся с гласной буквы, например: в обмен, в обрез, в обхват, в упор, в одиночку; также: в открытую.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/35.htm 
(Розенталь, §58.5)

Answer (score 0):

behemothus пытался Вам сказать, что есть наречия, а есть наречные выражения, которые пока не утратили смысла существительного с предлогом, поэтому нужно проверять вопросом к существительному "во что?"- в упор .

Это касается случая   "В + сущ., начинающееся с гласной" (в обрез, в упор, в одиночку)

А также сочет." сущ.+ без,до, на,с ":(до чего?-до отвала, до упаду);
                             на чём?-на скаку, на что?-на диво, на что? на  ощупь;
                               с чего?-(с размаху, со всего размаху,с ходу, со всего ходу);
Без чего?-без удержу, без устали

2) сущ. + предлог, если сохранены падежные формы(на корточки - на корточках
под мышкой - под мышку, из – под мышек )

Comment: Людмила, это Людмила, блондинка и Дилоетантка - это два навечно забаненных персонажа. Видимо - мульты также забаненного Гусляра. Не думаю, что реально их интересует вопрос.